# finding non zero entries in 3D matrix using only maps, lambda and reduce

Tags: python

I have a 3D matrix (tensor) which can be accessed as

```
m[x][y][z]
```

I want to find and save only the non zero elements.. with their index.. (as this matrix is sparse)..

So an equivalent code will be:

```
for i, x in enumerate(m):
      if x:
         for j,y in enumerate(x):
            if y:
               for k,z in enumerate(y):
                 if z:
                   print i,j,k, z
```

I want to get the similar effect but only using lambdas, map and reduce..

Comment: You could do it in one line with a list comprehension (basically the same code as above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pankaj Sharma mentioned, numpy is the best for matrix in Python.

Also you can use itertools:

```
from itertools import product

d3 = [[[0 for col in range(3)]for row in range(3)] for x in range(3)]

d3[0][2][2] = 1

for i, j, k in product(xrange(3), xrange(3), xrange(3)):
    if(d3[i][j][k]): print "%s %s %s = %s" % (i, j, k, d3[i][j][k])
```

Output:

0 2 2 = 1

If you still insist on Lambda/Map/Reduce:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # we need print as function to use within lamdba
d3 = [[[0 for col in range(3)]for row in range(3)] for x in range(3)]

d3[0][2][2] = 1
d3[1][2][2] = 2

d3 = reduce(list.__add__, reduce(list.__add__, d3))  # get flatten matrix

map(lambda x: print(x[0]/9, (x[0] - (x[0]/9)*9)/3, x[0] % 3, '=', x[1]), [(i, e) for i, e in enumerate(d3) if e != 0])

#print x / 9             # i
#print (x - (x/9)*9) / 3 # j
#print x % 3             # k
```

Output:

0 2 2 = 1

1 2 2 = 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy. 
Example:

```
import numpy as np
...
arr = np.arry(m)
non_zeros = np.transpose(np.nonzero(arr))
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ugly solution by using just map reduce filter
First map and filter to get new matrix with only non zero values with the indexes appended:

```
new_matrix = map(lambda (k,z):map(lambda (j,y):map(lambda (i,x):  [k,j,i,x], enumerate(filter( lambda val: val>0, y))), enumerate(z)), enumerate(m))
```

Then reduce it:

```
non_zeros = reduce(lambda a,b: reduce(lambda c,d: c+d, a)+reduce(lambda c,d: c+d, b), new_matrix)
```